# how to write conditions in regex

Tags: regex, bash

Trying regex for following strings

1. JIRAID-12314 >> should match
2. JIRAID-21312 test >> should match
3. JIRAID-12312-test >> should not match

```
if [[ $MESSAGE =~ ^$JIRAID-[0-9]{4,6}[\s\w]* ]];
then
    echo "string matched
    exit 0
```

How can I stop matching 3rd string?

Comment: What was your intent when you added `[\s\w]*`? What rule did you try to implement? What are the *conditions*?

Comment: in the third one is not matching because has a hyphen between 12312 and test?

Comment: You can use `^JIRAID-[0-9]{4,6}( [[:alnum:]]+)?$`

Comment: Did you mean you want to allow word or whitespace chars after `JIRAID-[0-9]{4,6}` pattern? Then why indicate `{4,6}` digits, if `[0-9]` is enough to require that part to start with a digit? Use `^JIRAID-[0-9][[:alnum:][:space:]_]*$`, and mind that `\w` != `[:alnum:]`

Comment: `^$` matches start followed by end, which does not make much sense, because everything after it is useless. It looks like you intended [`^JIRAID-[0-9]{4,6}[ \w]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/9XwzWR/1). An addition could be to add a `\b` *word boundary* after the digit part ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/DQ6KVw/1)).

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex in bash:

```
re='^JIRAID-[0-9]{4,6}( [[:alnum:]]+)?$'
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `JIRAID-`: Match `JIRAID-` text
- `[0-9]{4,6}`: Match 4 to 6 digits
- `( [[:alnum:]]+)?`: Optional group to match a space followed by 1+ alpha numeric characters
- `$`: End

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TUEiS6/1)

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/6YZ2ZT)

**Code:**

```bash
re='^JIRAID-[0-9]{4,6}( [[:alnum:]]+)?$'
 
for s in 'JIRAID-12314' 'JIRAID-21312 test' 'JIRAID-12312-test'; do
    [[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "$s matched" || echo "$s didn't match"
done
```

Comment: Awesome! Succinct and supported by precise demos!